# Xfce Run Preferred Web Browser with Argument

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, chrome

I am running Arch Linux and have Xfce4 installed along with Chromium. I want to make Chromium my default web browser, but unless I pass the option `--user-data-dir=/home/chris`, it doesn't start because I am the root user.

I have tried going to `Applications->Settings->Preferred Applications` in Xfce and setting the web browser to `/usr/bin/chromium "%s" --user-data-dir=/home/chris` (I have also switched `"%s"` and the option). However, when I click on the web browser icon in the bottom panel, I get the normal Chromium error (can't run as root) and another error

```
Failed to Execute default Web Browser - Input/Output Error
```

So, my question is how can I make Chromium the default web browser and pass the required argument every time it is started?

Answer (score 0):

You must not log in as root user. 
Either way, go to /usr/share/applications. There should be the .desktop file, copy it to your desktop or when you want and modify the line Exec with the order you want to execute. Then you just have to run chromium clicking on this file (you can use it like a desktop shortcut or a panel icon). If you want, you can also modify the original file and the change will take effect for every launcher of the system, and for every user.